# drupal based menu

Tags: drupal, menu

I built a website with a menu using drupal.
My question is how do I change slightly the design?
Do I have access to the css files? where?
Can I change the design using drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the default Drupal menu, you'd need access to the file system, specifically your site's theme files, to update the design. If you used a core theme, the theme would be in a subdirectory of your site's **/theme** directory. If you used a contributed theme, your theme should probably be located in a subdirectory of **/sites/all/themes**.

If you're unable to access the files but can somehow install modules, the following modules may help somewhat:

- [Sweaver](http://drupal.org/project/sweaver)
- [Live Themer](http://marmaladesoul.com/livethemer)